# What is the value of AssemblyLoadContext.Unload() in .NET Core in comparison with regular garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, assembly-loading, dynamic-assemblies

.NET Core 3.0 introduced collectible `AssemblyLoadContext`, which allows to call `Unload()` method to unload assemblies loaded inside the context.

As per documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability#troubleshoot-unloadability-issues), unloading is asynchronous and any reference to the context or objects from it will prevent context from unloading.

I was wondering what if I loose my reference to `AssemblyLoadContext`, will this cause a leak (since I have no more context to call `Unload()` on). The test proved that this won't cause a leak and unused assembly will be unloaded even without `Unload()` called explicitly:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests.Core
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CollectibleAssemblyLoadContextTests
    {
        private const string AssemblyName = "Test___DynamicAssembly";

        [Test]
        [TestCase(/*unload*/ true,  /*GC sessions*/ 1)]
        [TestCase(/*unload*/ false, /*GC sessions*/ 2)]
        public void ShouldExecuteAndUnload(bool unload, int expectedGcSessions)
        {
            string actual = Execute(10, unload);
            Assert.AreEqual("executed 10", actual);

            int gcSessions = 0;
            while (!IsUnloaded())
            {
                GC.Collect();
                gcSessions++;
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedGcSessions, gcSessions);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private bool IsUnloaded()
        {
            return !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .Select(x => x.GetName().Name)
                .Contains(AssemblyName);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private string Execute(int number, bool unload)
        {
            var source = @"
        public static class Process
        {
            public static string Execute(int i)
            {
                return $""executed {i}"";
            }
        }";
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(AssemblyName, new[] {CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source)},
                new []{MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)},
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            compilation.Emit(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var assemblyLoadContext = new AssemblyLoadContext("CollectibleContext", isCollectible: true);

            Assembly assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(ms);
            if (unload)
                assemblyLoadContext.Unload();

            Type type = assembly.GetType("Process");
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Execute");
            return (string)method.Invoke(null, new object[] {number});
        }
    }
}
```

What this test also shows is that using `Unload()` get the context unloaded after 1 GC session, whether without `Unload()` it takes 2 sessions to unload. But can be just coincidence and not always reproducible.

So, given that

1. Any references to collectible context will prevent it form unloading (so it is possible to call `Unload()` just after loading all the assemblies you need to schedule unload when it won't be in use).
2. Even without calling `Unload()` collectible context is unloaded once it is not in use anymore.

What is the purpose of this `Unload()` method and what is the difference between using `Unload()` and simply relying on GC?

Comment: This looks like exactly the same question as "What is the purpose of Dispose() method and what is the difference between using Dispose() and simply relying on GC?"

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Not really. Dispose is usually synchronous and it is not scheduled as Unload here. I can call Unload just after loading all the things to it, and anyways I will have to wait GC to collect it (and it won't while the context is in use). I can not follow the same pattern for Dispose.

Comment: Lasse's analogy is especially apt if we focus on how managed memory is released by Dispose.  After the call from Dispose returns, the caller still holds a reference to the object and the space on the heap is still taken up.  But if the object implemented a typical Dispose pattern, the Dispose call will opt out of finalization and the object will be garbage collected sooner than if it was left to go out of scope undisposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same impression and the tests I did showed the same. It looked like it doesn't make sense to call `Unload()` explicitly. Then I found https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/core/tutorials/Unloading and realized that if you comment `Unload()` there, the lib won't be unloaded. This is the line https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/core/tutorials/Unloading/Host/Program.cs#L74.
Eventually it is like Lasse V. Karlsen says. If you call `Unload()` explicitly, you can expect that your library will be unloaded faster.